# Does C# have (direct) flex/yacc port? Or what lexer/parser people use for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, lexer

I might be wrong, but it looks like that there's no direct flex/bison (lex/yacc) port for C#/.NET so far.

For LALR parser, I found GPPG/GPLEX, and for LL parser, there is the famous ANTLR. But, I want to reuse my flex/bison grammar as much as possible.

- Is there any direct port of flex/bison for C#?
- What lexer/parser people normally use for C#? Is there any reason for that choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lex/Yacc for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540593/lex-yacc-for-c)

Comment: @Hans: While the title may be similar the question isn't.

Comment: ANTLR only supports LL(k) grammars - bison supports LALR(1) grammars, which is much more powerful. I don't know of any parser-generator for .Net that even comes close to bison's power, so the question is very legit IMHO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be GPLEX/GPPG, it's the closest thing to Yacc/Lex for C# that I know of, and you will need to port your actions into C# regardless.

I have also used Coco/R, ANTLR (of course), and have more recently played with Irony.net, fslex/fsyacc (F#), and fparsec (F#).

Here are some links

[Fparsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/)

[Coco/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/)

[Irony.net](https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony)

[Gardens Point Parser Generator](http://gppg.codeplex.com/)

[Gardens Point Lex](http://gplex.codeplex.com/)

I don't have a technical reason for using one versus another: I play around with these mostly for fun. I did create some DSLs for work projects a good number of years ago, but I hand rolled the scanners/parsers on those (back then I was working mostly in Pascal, and I found that TP Lex/Yacc did not suit my tastes, and the DSLs were simple enough). I have found that FParsec and Irony suit my tastes the best, as I find the other somewhat "messy" (lacking in elegance).

Comment: Thanks for the update, Emyr

Answer (score 2):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) is a very mature (and awesome) parser/lexer generator. It originally produced Java code, but can now target several languages, [including C#](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target).

Comment: The above link is dead at the moment, on the [C# target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md) page we may find some information.

Comment: The [getting started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/CSharp/src) page is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "Managed babel" extensions, there is quite a classic-style port of lex and yacc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165037(VS.80).aspx

Comment: This link is dead