# Best way to parse a log file in C#

Tags: c#, text-parsing

I have the following log file:

```
START:SOME_STRING
BL:2
LK:3
LH:5
end
START:SOME_STRING
BL:5
LK:6
LH:6
end
```

Which has multiple START: -> end structures inside. Is there a better 'non-sloppy' way of parsing this file rather than reading line by line and using SPLIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to formalize your ini-file's grammar, and you some of parser generators. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540593/lex-yacc-for-c) for more detail.

Be aware howeveer that for such a simple grammar as  yours it might be easier to parse manually :-P

```
class IniEntry
{
    public int BL;
    public int LK;
    public int LH;
    IniEntry Clone() { return new IniEntry { BL = BL, LK = LK, LH = LH }; }
}

IEnumerable<IniEntry> Parse()
{
    IniEntry ie = new IniEntry();
    while (ParseEntry(out ie))
        yield return ie.Clone();
}

bool ParseEntry(out IniEntry ie)
{
    ie = new IniEntry();
    return ParseStart(ie) &&
               ParseBL(ie) &&
               ParseLK(ie) &&
               ParseLH(ie) &&
               ParseEnd(ie);
}

bool ParseStart(IniEntry ie)
{
    string dummy;
    return ParseLine("START", out dummy);
}

bool ParseBL(IniEntry ie)
{
    string BL;
    return ParseLine("BL", out BL) && int.TryParse(BL, out ie.BL);
}

bool ParseLK(IniEntry ie)
{
    string LK;
    return ParseLine("LK", out LK) && int.TryParse(LK, out ie.LK);
}

bool ParseLH(IniEntry ie)
{
    string LH;
    return ParseLine("LH", out LH) && string.TryParse(LH, out ie.LH);
}

bool ParseLine(string key, out string value)
{
    string line = GetNextLine();
    var parts = line.Split(":");
    if (parts.Count != 2) return false;
    if (parts[0] != key) return false;
    value = parts[1];
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thats the log file I was given to parse, unfortunately not subject to change.

Comment: You don't need to change the log file, why?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for a while loop and a state machine.
With this approach you would use even use less memory and have greater performance than using string.split()

Comment: Some further details on the state machine will get an up vote from me.

Comment: State machine? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Avoid the pitfall of doing things way too 'non-sloppy'. Unless you can reuse somehwre else the state mechine implementation you better thing twice if it's wort it. You coudl do the SPLIT option in far less time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is certain that the START/END are always matched, (apologies, my C# is embarrassing, so plain English):

```
Read the whole file with System.IO.ReadToEnd
Parse the whole thing in one go with a regular expression
Iterate over regex results
```

The regex would be something like "(START:([^$]+)$BL:([^$]+)$LK:([^$]+)$LH:([^$]+)$end$)+", off the top of my head, you'll need to validate/adjust according to how your parameters BL/LK etc. occur

Comment: This doesn't sounds efficient when some files I need read are over 6000 lines. Unless I am mistaken?

Comment: That's really a bad solution. Just imagine the file has a size of several hundred megs. Better read it line by line (or chunk by chunk) and use some kind of state machine.

Comment: Is memory really a problem? Even if it momentarily takes 1Gb of memory, so what? Of course, a state machine is more elegant, but this solves the problem quickly